# Rails first_or_initialize with condition on initialize

Tags: ruby-on-rails, race-condition

I try to make a `first_or_initialize` with condition on the initialize,

Here what I have :

```
def find_or_initialize_user(name)
    User.where(company: company).first_or_initialize(company: company, name: name)
end
```

And I would like to make the new record only if `company.can_add_user` is set to true,

Do you know how to make it ?

Comment: So, wrap this line in an `if`?

Comment: But if I wrap it in a `if` condition, it won't find the User. I would like to find the User or create a new one if my company can add user

Comment: that's what `else` is for. In pseudo-code, `if can_create_user then first_or_initialize else find`

Answer (score 0):

I believe the following should work:

```
User.joins(:company).where('companies.can_add_user').first_or_initialize(company: company, name: name)
```

The first part of that should translate to roughly the following SQL query

```
select * from users u
join companies c on u.company_id = c.id
where c.can_add_to_user = true
```